# Getting label name of extra user fields

Tags: plugins, user-meta

I'm using the plugin "Extra User Fields" to add extra fields to the user's profile. I know how to get the value of the field (get_user_meta/get_author_meta), but I also want the label as a string, but I don't want to get the full code (like `<label>Label</label><input value="value" />` etc., because I want to be able to do with the label and the value what I please.

So, what function (or tag) should I use to get the label value of an user field?

Comment: You can already get the label but you ALSO get the input with it right?

Comment: Yes, I just want the "values" as strings, not wrapped in html labels and inputs...

Comment: Could you post an example of what you've tried that isn't giving you the desired results?

Comment: Yes. `do_action( 'edit_user_profile', $profileuser );` gives me all the user profile fields (labels, input and help wrapped in html elements, ready for output to the browser), but I just want the label value on it's own. I can get the input value with `get_the_author_meta('field_id')`, but I have no idea how to get just the label value that goes with that input value..

Comment: The plugin appears to be intended for people to use in the administration area, are you extending the plugin or are you editing the plugin?

The plugin doesn't look like it supports PHP execution from the admin area - so I am just trying to get some context.

Answer (score 0):

- Context: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extra-user-fields/
- Author URL: http://www.feweb.net/wordpressplugin_extrauserfields.htm

Mentioned Functions:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

If you can already get the label BUT it comes with the input, and you are doing this in PHP, then do this:

```
<?php
    # ...
    # Your code which produces the input + label data into $data
    # ...
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML( $data );
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $document );
    $entries = $xpath->evaluate("//label");
    $results = array();
    foreach( $entries as $entry ) {
        $results[] = '<' . $entry->tagName . '>' . $entry->nodeValue .  '</' . $entry->tagName . '>';
    }
    print_r($results);
?>
```

This question appears incomplete from my outside perspective, so if this doesn't solve your problem, please refer to the discussion under the original question (in the comments section) so I may formulate a more appropriate response.

Comment: Oke, so what this does is load the data (label, input and someimes more) wrapped in the html-elements, and then parses that to get the desired strings? I've thought of that, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner/direct way to get the label. Anyway, thanks! I will try it like this!

Comment: If this answer was acceptable please mark it as "Accepted".

I'll see if I can look into a more efficient method - but for now this will do.